# Magento 2.4 System > Configuration > Catalog showing blank page at backend

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.2, magento2.1

At admin, the Catalog is showing a blank page at the backend. Can someone guide me on what is creating trouble.
FYI modules
Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch6
Magento_Elasticsearch7
Magento_TwoFactorAuth are disabled when I checked the status.
Also, while creating any custom category error log is showing.

Rashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is a requirement for magento 2.4

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html
```

You'll need to enable the elasticsearch extensions and also install elasticsearch to get things up and running

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I installed Elasticsearch on my system

Answer (score 0):

Your admin configuration is not displayed because your system has no full permission for `var/generation` folder. No new directory is generated because of the permission issue.

Please give full permissions for var generation folder, clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

- It is a permission related issue, please fire below commands and check.

```
chown -R owner:group /your magento root path
chmod 775 /your magento root path
php bin/magento cache:clean
```